# Selenium select an element with xpath in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to navigate to `/yandsearch?...` by clicking on the related links. There are two links in the page:

```
<a class="button button_theme_pseudo button_pseudo-pressed_yes button_size_m button_counter_yes button_focus_no b-link b-link_pseudo_yes pager__button pager__button_kind_page i-bem button_js_inited" onmousedown="w(this, '405.88');" href="/yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3" role="button" ondblclick="return {"button":{"counter":"w(this, '405.88');"},"b-link":{}}">
<a class="button button_theme_pseudo button_pseudo-pressed_yes button_size_m button_counter_yes button_focus_no b-link b-link_pseudo_yes pager__button pager__button_kind_page i-bem" onmousedown="w(this, '405.88');" href="/yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3" role="button" ondblclick="return {"button":{"counter":"w(this, '405.88');"},"b-link":{}}">
```

I try to select the first using:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(str('//*[contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3")] and [contains(@class,"button_js_inited")]')
```

It should click on the first item, but `find_element_by_xpath` can't find it.
I get the error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: 'The given selecto......
```

I want to click on page 4 at this link [yandex.by/yandsearch](http://yandex.by/yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad)

I tried it also:

```
//*[contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3") and contains(@class,"button_js_inited")]
```

writes an error:

```
self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "C:\Python34\lib\site- packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py" , 
line 164, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: 
Message: 'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//* [contains(@href,\\"yandsearch?lr=157&tex t=landsad&p=3\\") and contains(@class,\\"button_js_inited\\")]"}';
```

Comment: Always show full error message - and there is number of line with problem so mark this line in your code.

Comment: either your xpath code is incorrect or the element is not visible. Neither of which can be determined for sure without knowing what page you are trying to parse or the full error.Why are you using `str` to make a string that is already a string?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `//*[contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3")] and //*[contains(@class,"button_js_inited")]` or `//*[contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3") and contains(@class,"button_js_inited")]`

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is invalid, both criteria should be placed within the same square-brackets (formatted for readiblity) :

```
//*[
        contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3") 
            and 
        contains(@class,"button_js_inited")
   ]
```

Not formatted version :

```
//*[contains(@href,"yandsearch?lr=157&text=landsad&p=3") and contains(@class,"button_js_inited")]
```

Comment: I tried it too, writes an error:

    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-            packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py"
, line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable     to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*    [contains(@href,\\"yandsearch?lr=157&tex
t=landsad&p=3\\") and contains(@class,\\"button_js_inited\\")]"}' ; Stacktrace: